# How can I make tuples an instance of this class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-kinds

I've been reading the book "[What I wish I knew when learning Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/)" and I stopped on this example:

```
class Bifunctor p where
    bimap  :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
    first  :: (a -> b) -> p a c -> p b c
    second :: (b -> c) -> p a b -> p a c
```

My question is: How can I create an instance of that class? The idea is to call the function as:

```
λ bimap  (+1) (+2) (8, 9) -- (9, 11)
λ first  (*4) (10, 8) -- (40, 8)
λ second (*2) (3, 5) -- (3, 10)
```

The closest I came to accomplishing this was:

```
instance Bifunctor (x, y) where
    bimap func func' (x, y) = (func x, func' y)
    first func (x, y) = (func x, y)
    second func (x, y) = (x, func y)
```

But it doesn't work, it raises an error:

```
• Expecting two fewer arguments to ‘(x, y)’
  Expected kind ‘* -> * -> *’, but ‘(x, y)’ has kind ‘*’
• In the first argument of ‘Bifunctor’, namely ‘(x, y)’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Bifunctor (x, y)’
```

Comment: syntactically, `(a,b)` is the same as `(,) a b`, for values *and* types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good question.

The class applies to the functor type itself, and in your case the functor type is (,). To get the feeling about it, notice the difference here.

```
:t (,)
(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)

:t (True,False)
(True,False) :: (Bool, Bool)
```

It would probably have been more intuitive if you had used a Pair type like :

```
data Pair a b = Pair a b
```

Because reading the class definition would have made more obvious the type application of 'p'.

Just like Haskell uses types for values, as illustrated above, it uses types  for types (also for compile-time logic), which are named *Kinds*.

```
:k Pair
Pair :: * -> * -> *

:k (,)
(,) :: * -> * -> *

:k (Bool,Bool)
(Bool,Bool) :: *

:k Bifunctor 
Bifunctor :: (* -> * -> *) -> Constraint
```

This last line illustrates that Bifunctor class is designed for types of kind `(* -> * -> *)`, not kind `(*)` of (a,b), hence the error message you had from GHC.

Your definition was almost right, here is the correct one :

```
instance Bifunctor (,) where
  bimap func func' (x, y) = (func x, func' y)
  first func (x, y) = (func x, y)
  second func (x, y) = (x, func y)
```

**EDIT : illustration of *kinds* as suggested by @leftroundabout**

Comment: I'd note that when using `:t` on those _value-level_ entities, you're actually looking at something different from type-level entities used in the instance head. It so happens that for tuples, the type- end value constructors behave almost exactly the same way, but this is not true for most other types. In general, you want `:k`[ind] instead of `:t`[ype].

Comment: This is technically true, however I think in this case the value constructor example I chose illustrates enough the difference, while remaining easily accessible to the reader. But again your point is right, and reading about class parametrization and data kinds is recommended to better understand the error message.

Comment: This answer was validated, so I will edit it to reflect your good point.

Answer (score 7):

`(x,y)` is already a concrete tuple type, containing two concrete (albeit unknown) types `x` and `y`. A functor, or bifunctor, meanwhile is supposed to be *parametric*, i.e. in case of the tuple instance you'd want the contained types to be left open as parameters, which are then filled in with various different concrete types when the methods are used.

I.e., you basically want a *type-level lambda*

```
instance Bifunctor (\x y -> (x, y)) where
```

Well, Haskell doesn't have type-level lambdas, but it does have partial application at the type level – in this case not even *partial*, you don't want to apply the tuple constructor to any types *at all* but simply leave them open. That is written thus:

```
instance Bifunctor (,) where
```

If you wanted to apply it to only one argument, you write

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
```

which I find easier to understand if parsed as `Functor (a,)` – but that's not actually legal in Haskell.